# Large size image breaks template layout

Tags: images

If I upload a large size image inn my wordpress, the image breaks my template width. I have seen some templates which scale the large image's width to the maximum width of the post div.
What CSS or code I need to change for that purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `functions.php` file, you need to define `$content_width`, which will cause WordPress to scale **large**-size images, and also embedded videos, accordingly.

e.g. if the width of your content area is 600px:

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 600;
}
```

You will probably also want to add accompanying CSS, e.g.:

```
#content img {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
}
```

That way, when the image is scaled, it will maintain its proportion;  rather than merely having its width reduced, the height will also be scaled proportionately.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any CSS, just go to Settings > Media and adjust the Large image size width to that of your post container. You may need to [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) after doing that.